# Handsontable: change dropdownmenu width

Tags: javascript, typescript, handsontable

I've spent some time looking for possible solutions to this issue, and [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/handsoncode/zxguhohs/) seems the most suitable.

The code structure in my custom visual (PowerBI, Typescript) is the following:

```
export class Visual implements IVisual {
  private settings: VisualSettings;
  private host: IVisualHost;
  <...>
  private hot: Handsontable;

  constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
    <...>
    };
    this.hot = new Handsontable(hotElement, hotSettings);

    this.hot.addHook('modifyColWidth', function(width){
      if(this === this.hot.getPlugin('dropdownmenu').menu.hotMenu)
      {
        return 300;
      }
      return width;
    })
  }
```

The last piece of code outputs an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPlugin' of undefined
    at Core.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:65781:29)
    at Hooks.run (<anonymous>:10485:46)
    at Core.runHooks (<anonymous>:43381:89)
    at Core.getColWidth (<anonymous>:42643:22)
    at Table.getColumnWidth (<anonymous>:49386:17)
    at Table.getStretchedColumnWidth (<anonymous>:49396:30)
    at LeftOverlay.sumCellSizes (<anonymous>:83603:33)
    at Overlays.adjustElementsSize (<anonymous>:53065:69)
    at Object.adjustRowsAndCols (<anonymous>:40249:37)
    at Core.updateSettings (<anonymous>:41558:10)0
```

It seems that a hook doesn't see the intance of my visual, that's why IntelliSense doesn't offer anything for the plugin: `this.hot.getPlugin('dropdownmenu').menu.hotMenu`

Has anyone had the same issue? Can you assist?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add global hook instead of local, and check if binded instance to whom hook will be applied is a part of dropdownMenu from "hot" you've defined.

```js
const self = this;
Handsontable.hooks.add('modifyColWidth', function (width) {
  if (this === (self.hot.getPlugin('dropdownMenu').menu as Menu).hotMenu) {
    return 300;
  }
  return width;
});
```

Comment: Alright, it's getting closer, now the error is this:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'menu' of undefined

Maybe there is something to do with the name of the plugin, let me see...

Comment: Yes, if believe to provided fiddle example - plugin name should be "dropdownMenu", it's case-sensitive.

Comment: So, i've corrected the 'dropdownmenu' to 'dropdownMenu', this error is gone. 


Next error: "ReferenceError: width is not defined
    at eval (eval at Visual (:65779:5), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at new Visual (<anonymous>:65779:5)
    <....>


Adding (function(width: any) didn't really help

Comment: I also tried to follow the Option #2 - in this one, this.hot.getPlugin('dropdownMenu').menu does not see a hotMenu, though this property exists inside the Menu interface like this:

interface Menu { hotMenu: _Handsontable.Core }

Comment: Conditions `plugin.menu` && `plugin.menu.hotMenu` pass successfully, though for the third condition the output is: 
`This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'this' and 'Core' have no overlap.ts(2367)`

Comment: Ah yes, we should not bind context from outside. Hook will be applied to specified context via running hooks process, so "this" will become Core instance, Menu instance or anything else. Just write it as you've mentioned before through `function(width) { ... }`. I'll update my answer

Comment: The error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPlugin' of undefined` is back again...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198794/discussion-between-mayakwd-and-hardrock4life).